# best way to load 100mb+ json file nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, axios

I have a system that generates data every day
And saves the data in the json file. The file about 120MB

I'm trying to send the data with nodejs to the client

```
router.get('/getData',(req, res) => {

    const newData = require(`./newDataJson.json`)
    res.json(newData)`});
```

and then from the client i use axios get request

```
    const fetchNewData = async () => {
const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/getData/`);}
```

The data reaches the client within about 3 minutes in production.
and few second in localhost.

My question is if it possible to Shorten the load time in production.

thanks !!

Comment: What are you trying to do with 100MBs+ of data on the client? Maybe sort out the "system that generates data every day" to not create a giant file but to store data in a folder by the hour(?), and then you can use an endpoint to access/stream bits of data at a time.

Comment: If the file is already JSON you don’t need to use `res.json` - that is likely double wrapping it.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use [stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) in Node.js that is suitable to send the large data from server to client. Stream are useful when you send big chunk of data. You should give it a try and check if there are any improvements after adding this.

```
const readStream = fs.createReadStream('./newDataJson.json');
return response.headers({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="newDataJson.json"',
}).send(readStream);
```

Also, as Andy suggested this could be a way to divide your file data in smaller partition based on hours.

Answer (score 1):

120 MB is way over the limits of initial page loading times. The best thing to do would be to split the file into smaller chunks:

1.
Right after that the user will see the loaded page you need (as I assume) only portion of that data. So initially send only small chunk to make the data visible. Keep it small, so the data would not block loading and first draw.

2.
Keep sending rest of the data in smaller parts or load them on demand in chunks e.g. with pagination or scroll events.

You can start splitting the data upon receiving/saving them.

Loading data from api on scroll (infinite scroll)
https://kennethscoggins.medium.com/using-the-infinite-scrolling-method-to-fetch-api-data-in-reactjs-c008b2b3a8b9

Info on loading time vs response time
https://www.pingdom.com/blog/page-load-time-vs-response-time-what-is-the-difference/

Comment: Do you know some general rule of thumb like keep size of first json at initial load < X MB? Every further chunk < X MB?